# R: Moving window

Tags: r, moving-average, sliding-window

I have a dataset like this:

```
> head(test,20)
         Temp    Precip     species
3   9.4007956  59.27015         oak
4  -0.4519635  47.40692  scots_pine
5  11.6495457  64.51529       beech
6   5.2807114 101.44833 picea_abies
9   5.3833591  53.95441  scots_pine
10  7.3652109  88.80829 picea_abies
11  8.9340262  69.37932       beech
13  8.8422581  94.94867 picea_abies
14  4.2412035  55.40555  scots_pine
27  4.2412035  55.40555 picea_abies
28 10.4218126  63.84373       beech
29  8.5513810  89.79829       beech
32 10.8957457  58.20228         oak
35  7.6330249  55.74190       beech
38  4.1350583 105.62783 picea_abies
39  4.7160738  58.02741 picea_abies
40 10.1936149  66.41384         oak
41  5.9420923  81.82859       beech
45  8.9224902  50.62589  scots_pine
46  9.0305198  49.18080  scots_pine
```

I want to create different bins for each species to describe the different climate conditions that the species are distributed in. An example output would be that Picea abies may overall live in 2 different bins of temperature-precipitation that include most of the species plots, one in 4-8ºC and 60mm rainfall and the other characterised by 4-8ºC and 100mm rainfall. I want R to tell me which bins are the best to explain and group the climate distribution of these species.

How can I do this in R automatically? I have been told moving windows are useful but I have no idea how I can automate this in R.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: What is the desired result suppose to look like?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. the desired output is which bins or thresholds of temperature and precipitation, for each species, can group most of the data, as described in my example.

Comment: Maybe exploring data visually would be a first step... you could create different dataframes (for convenience, one per species) and then use different basic plotting tools like histograms/barplots.

Comment: My supervisor has asked me to use moving windows and I have no idea about it, so I am into trouble